# Run multiple child processes in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, spawn

I want to run "npm init -y && npm i express" in node child process

I tried

1)

```js
const npmInit = spawn("npm", ["init", "-y"], {
      cwd: projectFolder,
      stdio: "inherit",
    });

    npmInit.on("close", () => {
      const expressInstall = spawn("npm", ["install", "express"], {
        cwd: projectFolder,
        stdio: "inherit",
      });
    });
```

2. spawnSync("npm init -y && npm install express", {
   cwd: projectFolder,
   shell: true
   })
3. 

```
exec("sh path_to_file.sh")
```

Nothing works for me

It execute "npm init -y" but then nothing without any error

node -v v18.16.0